# Why is an element’s line-height (in pixels) affected by its parent’s font-size?

Tags: css

See this example:

http://codepen.io/tomsoderlund/pen/JYJpPR

Try dragging the slider, which affects the `font-size` on the `canvas` element. But why does the `line-height` on the green boxes change? The line height is set in pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<span>`s are `inline` elements. Those are not affected by `line-height` as you wish.

replace the `<span>`s with `<div>`s or set CSS to `display: block`

> On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the
>   minimum height of line boxes within the element.
>
> On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that
>   is used to calculate line box height. On replaced inline elements such
>   as buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Answer (score 1):

Use `.box span` as block element

```
.box span {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This may be a solution to the problem, but the question asks why. A explanation would be helpful.